# Input argument to learner.predict in fastai

Tags: python, deep-learning, fast-ai

I've been trying to work with the MNIST fashion dataset using Fastai. I successfully reshaped the data, stacked the channels (to convert them from 1 to 3) and then saved the images as `.jpeg` files.

The model creation and fit is as follows:

[image]

The model was trained with Resnet18 and now I'm trying to predict an image but encounter the following error:

[image]

Using tensors has resulted in the following error:
[image]

I have tried using tensors, NumPy arrays, and images but none seem to work. The Kaggle notebook link is as follows:

https://www.kaggle.com/namansood/fastai-image-channel

What can I give as input to the model for a successful prediction?

Comment: according to the [docs](https://docs.fast.ai/learner#Learner.predict) learn.predict takes a `tensor` object

Comment: updated question with tensor error logs